# FFMpeg rtsp to m3u8

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using **FFMPeg (version ffmpeg-20170330-ad7aff0-win64-static) to convert RTSP to .m3u8.**

The command is:

ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i {**RTSP**} -c:v libx264 -crf 35 -preset ultrafast -maxrate 3M -bufsize 300k -r 10 -g 20 -movflags +faststart -tune zerolatency -hls_time 1 -hls_list_size 4 -hls_wrap 4 -start_number 1 -hls_allow_cache 0 -threads 1 -loglevel warning -y {**PLAYLISTM3U8LOCATION**]

I am getting following warning constantly:

**Duplicated segment filename detected: playlist1.ts**

or

**Duplicated segment filename detected: playlist2.ts**

or

**Duplicated segment filename detected: playlist3.ts**

In between its also showing warning:

**cseq 10 expected, 8 received**

any help on this??

Answer (score 2):

I have met with a problem like so.My solution is to set the hls_wrap`s value larger than the hls_list_size`s.Maybe it can help you.